# returning list of mysql_fetch_array while echo without repeating other text

Tags: mysql, arrays, fetch

I'm trying to echo out a series of rows from MySQL database using mysql_fetch_array while loop into a table with form. I tried not to repeat the form-table and /table-/form tag but only repeat tr.../tr tag while echoing.

Although, it is also repeating form-table and /table-/form tags.
Can anybody please help. I just want tr.../tr to be repeated. 
Below is the code:

```
$topmessage = '<form><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">';

$bottommessage = '</table><div align="right"><input type="submit" name="approveimage" value="Approve" /><input type="submit" name="disapproveimage" value="Disapprove" /></div></form>';

$multirowing = '';

require("../connect.php");
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM imagegallery WHERE approve ='0'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
while($rowphew = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $multirowing .= '<tr>
       <td>' . $rowphew['username'] . '</td>
       <td>
           <a href="uploads/' . $rowphew['image'] . '">
              <img src="uploads/' . $rowphew['image'] . '" width="100px" />
           </a>
       </td>
       <td>
           <input type="checkbox" name="selectingimage" value="' . $rowphew['image'] . '" />
       </td>
    </tr>';
 }
$message =  $topmessage . $multirowing . $bottommessage;
echo $message;
```

The outcome result (as shown in source code) given is: (sorry cant upload image as need 10 reputation points..ahh)

```
<form><table>
<tr><td>Image1</td></tr>
</table>BUTTONS</form>

<form><table>
<tr><td>Image1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image2</td></tr>
</table>BUTTONS</form>

<form><table>
<tr><td>Image1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image3</td></tr>
</table>BUTTONS</form>

<form><table>
<tr><td>Image1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image4</td></tr>
</table>BUTTONS</form>

<form><table>
<tr><td>Image1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image5</td></tr>
</table>BUTTONS</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure that some other file isn't including this file in a loop?

Comment: ***STOP*** using the `mysql_` family of PHP functions, they're DEPRECATED and NSECURE. You want to [use `mysqli_` functions instead](https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/9199/post/3-Smoothly-Migrate-your-PHP-Code-using-the-Old-MySQL-extension-to-MySQLi.html).

Comment: please find the image at [link](http://burhaniconsultancy.com/outcome.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to append strings to `$multirowing`, not to replace it. And you should use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.htmlentities.php).

```
$topmessage = '<form><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">';

$bottommessage = '</table><div align="right"><input type="submit" name="approveimage" value="Approve" /><input type="submit" name="disapproveimage" value="Disapprove" /></div></form>';

$multirowing = '';

require("../connect.php");
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM imagegallery WHERE approve ='0'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
while($rowphew = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $multirowing .= '<tr>
        <td>' . htmlentities($rowphew['username']) . '</td>
        <td><a href="uploads/' . htmlentities($rowphew['image']) . '"><img src="uploads/' . htmlentities($rowphew['image']) . '" width="100px" /></a></td>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectingimage" value="' . htmlentities($rowphew['image']) . '" />
        </td>
    </tr>';
 }
$message =  $topmessage . $multirowing . $bottommessage;
echo $message;
```

Comment: If it still repeats the <table> tag, then most likely you running this code from another loop.

Comment: @MustafaAliasgar it's better if you take the contents of your comments and **update your original question** with the added information at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact the msql_query has been deprecated (you should beter move to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)).

You're setting `$multirowing = '<tr>....'`

I think you want this changed to `$multirowing .= '<tr>....'`

Is this inside another loop?

Comment: Or they can use `MySQLi_` It can be a bit of a big ask for someone to re-learn from procedural to OO programming (PDO).